# managing checkbox visibility on listview onItemClick

Tags: android, listview, checkbox

I have listview and list_item layout contains a imageview, textview and checkbox. my adapater contains  sectionheader. When I click on listview item make that checkbox visble and when I again click on that item make checkbox invisible.

```
        ListView lv = (ListView) findViewById(R.id.friendsList);
        lv.setFastScrollEnabled(true);
        fbAdapter = new FbFriendsAdapter(this, 0);
        lv.setAdapter(fbAdapter);
        lv.setChoiceMode(ListView.CHOICE_MODE_MULTIPLE);
        lv.setOnItemClickListener(new OnItemClickListener() {
            @Override
            public void onItemClick(AdapterView<?> parent, View view,
                    int position, long id) {
                // TODO Auto-generated method stub

                 fbAdapter.getSelectedFriend();

                 String s = (String) ((TextView) view
                 .findViewById(R.id.friendName)).getText();
                 CheckBox cb = (CheckBox) view.findViewById(R.id.iv_check);
                 cb.setVisibility(View.VISIBLE);

                 cb.setChecked(true);

                 if (cb.isChecked()) {

                     Toast.makeText(FbFriendsListActivity.this, "selected " + s,
                 Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
                 }
                 else{
                     //not working when i tried . setvisibilty gone of checkbox.

                 }
             });
```

listitemlayout:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<LinearLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    xmlns:tools="http://schemas.android.com/tools"
    xmlns:app="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res-auto"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent"
    android:orientation="vertical" >

    <LinearLayout
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:orientation="horizontal"
        android:padding="5dp" >

        <com.hashmash.utils.RoundedImageView
            android:id="@+id/friendPhoto"
            android:layout_width="wrap_content"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:focusable="false"
            android:src="@drawable/fb_profileimgsm"
            android:scaleType="centerCrop"
            app:corner_radius="80dp" />

        <LinearLayout
            android:layout_width="match_parent"
            android:layout_height="match_parent"
            android:layout_marginLeft="30dp"
            android:orientation="horizontal" >

            <TextView
                android:id="@+id/friendName"
                android:layout_width="wrap_content"
                android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                android:focusable="false"
                android:text="#Name"
                android:textColor="@color/instablue"
                android:textSize="14sp" />

            <RelativeLayout
                android:layout_width="match_parent"
                android:layout_height="match_parent"
                android:gravity="right" >

                <CheckBox
                    android:id="@+id/iv_check"
                    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
                    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                    android:focusable="false"
                    android:visibility="visible" />
            </RelativeLayout>
        </LinearLayout>
    </LinearLayout>

</LinearLayout>
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

i have got it using below snippet.

```
 if (view.findViewById(R.id.iv_check).getVisibility() == View.VISIBLE) {
                    view.findViewById(R.id.iv_check).setVisibility(View.INVISIBLE);
                } else {
                    view.findViewById(R.id.iv_check).setVisibility(View.VISIBLE);


                }
```

Answer (score 0):

You are checking checkbox before if else block.

```
cb.setChecked(true);

if (cb.isChecked()) {

    Toast.makeText(FbFriendsListActivity.this, "selected " + s,
                 Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
}          
else{
    cb.setVisibility(View.INVISIBLE); //or GONE if you don't need blank space occupied by checkbox
}
```

So your checkbox cb is always checked, and else never gets executed.

Just remove

```
cb.setChecked(true);
```

And it should work fine.

Answer (score 0):

I think you should have a `HashMap<Integer, Boolean>` or `ArrayList` or maybe `SparseBooleanArray` for the items with `CheckBox` visible. For example:

```
HashMap<Integer, Boolean> checkedItems = new HashMap<Integer, Boolean>();
```

When user clicks on item:

```
lv.setOnItemClickListener(new OnItemClickListener() { 
        @Override 
        public void onItemClick(AdapterView<?> parent, View view,
                int position, long id) {

            HashMap<Integer, Boolean> checkedItems = new HashMap<Integer, Boolean>();
            if (!checkedItems.containsKey(position))
                checkedItems.put(position, false);

            checkedItems.put(position, !checkedItems.get(position));

            mAdapter.notifyDataSetChanged();
         });
```

And in your adapter show the `checkbox` according to this `HashMap`.

If you do this way, it will be in guarantee. Android redraw list items on scroll. So even if you it right in your way, the checkboxes will be gone on use scroll.